# Databricks deserialize json stored as string in a dataframe column

Tags: json, pyspark, deserialization, databricks

Setup is that I'm using a Kepware server to send, for now, test data to an IoT hub in Azure, from here data is stored in a Data Lake Storage as json.

From here I've managed to fetch data from the files stored in this location and unbase the data, which leaves me with a dataframe looking like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4PL1.png)

The schema being:

```
root
 |-- values: string (nullable = true)
```

Now from here I would like to have the values column split up. As can be seen, the string is a json array (Databricks hasn't figured this out yet), and I would like to be able to split each element in each array into its own row in a data frame, without tampering with string.

I've tried to:

```
schema = F.schema_of_json(df.select('values').head()[0])
df1 =df.withColumn("values", F.explode(F.from_json("values", schema))).select("values")
display(df1)
df1.printSchema()
```

This give me almost what I would like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qVwN.png)

but as can be seen the explode values have been changed, `"v":9` has been changed to `"v":"9"` hence I've lost information about data type, which is what I would like to be able to retrieve. The same way if I send a tag with `"v":"false"` it's incorrectly in the above method identified as a string and not bool. If I only send data from my source of e.g. double, the `"v"` is correctly identified as a double, but as soon as multiple data types are sent, I lose the information.

It doesn't work if I lose data type information for each row and they all just becomes string.

It might be that this is not the right way and there is a smarter way to parse json, but I haven't been able to figure out how, the issue seems to be, that when I receive data from multiple tags in Kepware, then they are bundle in the way shown in the first picture no matter the data type.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Stated in about description

Comment: Just wondering, can you maybe try what happens with some sample data that has value for the `v` column as purely integer ? Does it convert even in that case ? Just want to understand if the other records having boolean and string values caused the entire column to be read as a string...

Comment: No then it doesnt convert to string, then it gets it to either number or double.

Comment: That kind of explains it right - basically Spark is going through your data to infer its type - Seeing as the column contains varying datatypes it is inferring the safe bet as string - you could try filtering out contents and then cast the resulting type as Integer...Not sure if there are any other automated ways to do it...

Comment: I haven't been able to figuring out how I can filter it out and I do not think there is a straight way forward. This issue seems to resolve around how Kepware transmit its data to IoTHub

Comment: you are right...I am not sure if there is a straight forward way to do it...But I have seen a couple of options - not sure if they would be applicable or even work for you...Option 1. Create a temp table of sorts, check if the column is numeric (You might need to create a simple UDF for it) and filter away. **Option 02:** Not sure how you would force it, but basically create a schema and then filter out/drop stuff not matching that schema, if it is a file read, the file read modes would work e.g. PERMISSIVE etc etc, but not sure how we can do that after read...Sorry if this is not of much help

Comment: Option 1 I don't think is viable, at least I cannot see how that can be done, option 2 on the other hand I might actually give a shot, at least until I run into something that is infeasible, I like the train of thought at least.

Comment: Hope it helped in some way...Regarding option 01, just create a table on top of the dataframe you get after reading the json - to check if it is a numeric value you could try casting it as an integer or bigint inside a case statement or in a where clause e.g. `CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS INTEGER) IS NOT NULL` and if it ends up being null, then you could filter it out or maybe use regular expressions ? e.g. `rlike(Column_Name, , '^[0-9]*$')`